# several instances of a prototype object, only last one gets persisted

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am having a problem with using an object as a prototype for some other objects.

The below code is expected to persist all instances of the object Container (visible in this code below is $module1 and $module2), however only the last one is persisted, and I assume it is due to the way I copy a prototype object.

Should I copy the prototype in some other way?

```
//Create module prototype
        $module = new Container();
        $module->setCompany($currentCompany);
        $module->setContainerType($typeModule);
        $module->setParent($entity);

        //Set the modules in use by this template (structure a bit ugly here, but makes it easier when dealing with the layout on other areas of the app)
        if ($size = $template->getModule1()) {
            $module1 = $module; //copy the prototype
            $module1->setName('Module1'); //Give a unique name
            $module1->setContainerSize($size); //Copy the size from the layoutTemplate
            $em->persist($module1); //Persist this module
            $layout->setModule1($module1); //Connect this container to become a module in the layout
        }

        if ($size = $template->getModule2()) {
            $module2 = $module; //copy the prototype
            $module2->setName('Module2'); //Give a unique name
            $module2->setContainerSize($size); //Copy the size from the layoutTemplate
            $em->persist($module2); //Persist this module
            $layout->setModule2($module2); //Connect this container to become a module in the layout
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really copy the object, you only create a new variable alias to the same object (they use the same underlying object). This would work with arrays, but not with objects.

You can use `clone` to create a (shallow) copy of an object:

```
$module1 = clone $module;
```

Keep in mind though that $module and $module1 will have the same objects referenced. I,e if ContainerType is an object, the $module and $module1 will reference the same instance of ContainerType, which may or may not be what you want.

You can [read more about cloning in PHP5 here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php)

Comment: Just what I suspected, and you gave me exactly what I needed - many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure about this because I don't have any experience with this framework.

But in your if-statement, you are missing one equal-sign to compare the values together.

```
if ($size = $template->getModule1()) {
```

Should be

```
if ($size == $template->getModule1()) {
```

The if's you have will always be true and the values will be overwritten in the second if's statement. Try changing both of these lines like suggested and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Oh, no that is intentional, I use that $size variable a few lines down instead of having to repeat that function call from the condition =)